# Execute a task all x seconds

Tags: java, android

I have an `class` who send notification when my value `live == true`.

**But how i can do for :**
Launch every x seconds this activity in background.

*Exemple : If the app is in background task but not running, she will execute this class all x seconds in background.*

This app send a notification when my value is on `true`. But i need to refresh this result all 15m (15000 ms i think).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: not sure if i got you right. do you mean, `class` will execute if the app is in background? the `class` will test for boolean value of `live` every 15min. If true, the `class` will trigger notification?

Comment: Yes it's this :) It's just i need to have a `class` because i need get `JSON from URL`, get the `value` and `stock` it into a `boolean`. So i want `execute` this `class` all 15 minutes

Comment: why 15min? to make sure that the data arrives in completeness?

Comment: It's a exemple 15m, i dont know now how much time i need

Comment: so you just want to keep on checking until the data has arrived?

Comment: No really. i'll try to explain the best i can : I create an app for a streamer (twitch). I get the JSON of the channel. When i have it i stock the boolean. If the boolean is "true", i send a notification, if he is false i didn't do anything. It's why i want refresh this class all x minutes / x seconds. For alert the user when live stream is ON.

Comment: alright. i will edit my answer below to give you an alternative and easier way.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) You'r previous anwerd work done. But when i close app in my "background app list" i didn't have another notification.

Comment: if you exit your app or press Home key of your phone, your activity can be stopped or destroyed as mentioned in Activity-Lifecycle documentation. To make your app work even if it is in the background, you need to put your `class` in a Service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the Activity lifecycle so that you will know how to determine if an activity is in the background.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Once your are clear with that, you can use `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule your `class`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: If you are just waiting for the whole data to arrive, there is no need for checking every x minutes. You can use AsyncTask for simpler implementation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html